# AWS SDK using Mono Timeout error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, mono, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to run a console app that connects to DynamoDb using mono, it runs fine from visual studio, but after compiling the program and running it on the Ubuntu server I get the following output:

```
[dev@dev Debug]$ mono Server.exe
Attempting call
Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, type Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.CertificateValidationCallback2
Missing method .ctor in assembly /usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, type Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.CertificateValidationCallback2

Unhandled Exception:
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: The request timed out ---> System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.handleHttpWebErrorResponse (Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncResult asyncResult, System.Net.WebException we) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: The request timed out ---> System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.handleHttpWebErrorResponse (Amazon.Runtime.Internal.AsyncResult asyncResult, System.Net.WebException we) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

This is the code I was running

```
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // adding this has no affect, this is never even called
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) => true;

            using (var ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(DynamoServer.Region))                                                                                                                                                            egion))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Attempting call");
                Console.WriteLine(ddb.ListTables());    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with both Mono 3.0.12 and 2.10.8 and both had the same error, I'm using AWSSDK 1.5.26.3. The project I used to build Server.exe target .net 4.0, I simply ran xbuild Server.csproj to build it

I would guess that it has something to do with ssl and the Missing method messages, can anyone offer any suggestions or ways to debug this further? I can't seem to find reports of this same error happening previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And immediately after posting this I found [this old bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=597230) that lead me to the problem

The problem was from my including an old Mono.Security.dll that was a requirement for Thrift. By deleting that out of date dll I was able run without error